# Robot framework no output inside log.html when tests fail

Tags: python, robotframework

I have a python script which I run as a test in robot framework. The test is configured to log the `stdout` and `stderr` which works fine as long as the test pass but I get no logs when test fails even if the output is printed before the failure.

Is there any way to get the `stdout` even if the tests fails.

My robot file:

```
*** Settings ***
Library   Process


*** Test Cases ***
First test
    ${result} =     Run Process     python    createCommunityTest/createCommunityTest.py
    Should Be Equal As Integers     ${result.rc}    0    
    Log     ${result.stderr} 
    Log     ${result.stdout}
```

test script snippet

```
        if res.status == 201: 
            sys.exit(0)
        else:
            print("ERRRROR")
            sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: Think it might be down to, RF just stopping the test on fail. So it never actually reaches the 2 log commands... Test it by placing the log before the failed part.

Comment: I did that, I wrote that also in the question....

Comment: Show where you "did that". We need to see how you are logging the result before failing the test case. As written, if the `Run process` keyword or `Should be equal as integers` fails, the log statements will never run.

Comment: Yes it fails because of that reason... because I don't return a sys.exit(0) but a sys.exit(1)

Comment: You are misunderstanding the question.  It doesn't matter how your process fails. What matters is when you terminate the test by calling `Should be equal as integers`.

Comment: @Jacob - I legitly told you exactly what Bryan said to do in his answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling `Log` *after* the test has failed. When you check the return code and the return code is not zero, the test immediately stops running any other statements.

You can solve this simply by calling the `Log` keyword before checking the return code.

```
Log     ${result.stderr} 
Log     ${result.stdout}
Should Be Equal As Integers     ${result.rc}    0
```

Comment: So obvious but could not see it. Thanks